# Hide element when scroll bar is not at the top

Tags: javascript

I have a big navigation bar that I want to hide everytime the scroll bar is not at the top position.

So basically, I have the idea of having two navigation bar, overlapping each other.
One with the larger height is on top (having a larger z-index) and the smaller one with the same navigation but with a small width is below it.

I want something that when the user scrolls his mouse wheel down/ drags the scroll bar, use a  keyboard to scroll down even a little, the big navigation bar will disappear (more like hide), leaving the smaller one on top.

I did a trick that the one with higher height is scrollable (not fixed) and the one below is fixed.

But I find it awkward. So instead, I want to hide it when the user scrolls down and show it again when the scroll bar is at the top.

Basically, it's like a windows taskbar in autohide mode. But it will hide when the user scrolls down and show when the scroll bar is on top :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple jQuery function that will show or hide a element `<ElementID>` in this case dependant on the scrollTop position.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('#<ElementID>').show();
        } else {
            $('#<ElementID>').hide();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I tried this script and, wow, it worked! now, I have another follow up question, how would I animate it like it hides itself up? Like how autohide taskbar in wondows work? I know it something like animate() but I'm not exactly sure where i'd put it :))

Comment: Ow sorry. i figured it out now. I inserted a number inside the hide() so it looks now like hide("3"). Thanks!

Comment: Nooooo... why would you do that? That is putting *way* too much work on the browser when scrolling...

Answer (score 3):

You can use some simple JS to do this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var top = document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0;
    document.getElementById('topbar').style.display = top ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('scollbar').style.display = top ? 'none' : 'block';
};
```

Substitute IDs as relevant to your code.